# How to use Symbol.iterator with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am rewriting my old app written in React JavaScript to React Typescript. In my old app the code I am trying to reuse worked perfectly fine, but TS does not like it and I am not sure why - it is also my first time using TS.

I'm exporting my data type:

```
export type CartItemType = { 
.....
id: number;
name: string;
.....
}
```

And getting my cartItems and data through hooks

```
 const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([] as CartItemType[]);
 const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery<CartItemType[]>(
            'products',
            getProducts
        );
```

I am mapping through data as usual

```
data?.map((item) => {
        return (
......
)}
```

Now, each of my data object has different variants of colors and I would like to be able to switch between them.

This is my approach:

```
function handleColorChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newData = [...data];
        let changedItem = {
            ...data.find((i) => i.name === selectedData.name),
        };
        let changedItemIndex = data.findIndex(
            (i) => i.name === selectedData.name
        );
        changedItem.chair.selected = e.target.value;
        newData[changedItemIndex] = changedItem;
        setSelectedColor(newData);
    }
```

To explain code above, I am trying to handle each color change where `selectedData` are just data of clicked product and `chair.selected` is default color value of specific product.

I am mapping through all the colors of specific product from my data object

```
{Object.values(selectedData.chair.colors).map(
 (key) => {
           return (
              <ItemButtonChair hex={key.hex} name={key.name} image={key}
                              click={handleColorChange}
               ></ItemButtonChair>
           );})}
```

ItemButtonChair is custom made by me

```
function ItemButtonChair(props) {
    let colorHeaderClassName = `selected ${props.click}`;

    return (
        <input
            type="button"
            value={props.name}
            name={props.name}
            onClick={props.click}
            className={colorHeaderClassName}
            style={{
                backgroundColor: props.hex,
                color: props.hex,
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

When I am trying to run this approach I am hetting error of `Type 'CartItemType[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.` I tried to Google it how to fix that, but it seems like every case with this error is very custom, and I simply don't understand why TS does not like it.

Answer (score 1):

The type error actually tells you the problem: the type of `data` is `CartItemType[] | undefined`, so it can be `undefined`, which you can't iterate over. *Although since you don't have a stacktrace or point it out, I don't know which `...data` is causing it and whether it has a type guard or so.*

If you're sure `data` exists at that point, you can use `...data!` to tell TypeScript "I'm sure this isn't `null`/`undefined`".

Comment: Thanks @KelvinSchoofs, error is pointing out to `data` in `handleColorChange` function. I don't know how they can be undefined, since I am mapping through them and I am getting my objects normally. I already tried to use  `...data!`, but it still seems not correct, since then the `changedItem.chair.selected` is underfined...and I really don't know why

Comment: You're calling `handleColorChange` from inside the map? TypeScript doesn't realize that `handleColorChange` only gets called when `data` is set, so it's back to being `... | undefined` within the function. Changing `data` to `data!` within that function should be enough. Something similar might be happening to `changedItem.chair.selected`. If you're sure those fields exist, you can do e.g. `changedItem.chair!.selected`.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that works, it is probably not a good practise to do it that way, so I will not mark it as a solution, but it does work!

So basically instead of one state I create more, for each object I have.

`selectedColor1`, `selectedColor2`, ......

And in the `handleColorChange` function setting each state:

```
setSelectedColor1(newData[0]);
setSelectedColor2(newData[1]);
............
```

I am able to achieve what I needed with this approach and colors of each object gets updated on click.